# How does adding $0$ to the set $\mathbf A = \bigl\{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N \bigr\}$ make it a closed set?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

By definition, a closed set is a set that contains its limit points. However, by the time the closed set contains its limit points, those points are no longer limit points and become isolated points. For example:

$\mathbf A = \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb N \}$. The limit of this set (set $\mathbf A$) is clearly equal to $0$. This is because the $\epsilon$ -neighborhood $\mathbf V_{\epsilon}(0) \cap \mathbf A = \{\frac{1}{n} \}$, and $\frac{1}{n} \neq 0$. However, when $0$ is included, the $\epsilon$ -neighborhood $\mathbf V_{\epsilon}(0) \cap \mathbf A = \{0 \}$ for $\mathbf A=[0,\frac{1}{n} ]$. This will contradicts the definition of limit point of set A and hence $0$ must be an isolated point.

Another example: $\left(a,b\right)$ is an open interval with limit $a$ and $b$. Then its closure $\bar A$ will be $\left[a,b\right]$. By definition, the $\epsilon$ -neighborhood of any point in $\left[a,b\right]$ intersects the closure $\bar A$ at that same point, and hence, no points in that closure set is a limit point: A contradiction that closure sets are closed sets.

Also, I am trying to prove the lemma: If x is a limit point of $A \subseteq A'$, then x is limit point of $A'$.
Proof: Suppose x is a limit point of $A$, then there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ $\subset A \subseteq A'$: lim($a_n$)=x with $a_n$ $\neq x \forall n \in \mathbb N$. Then since $(a_n)$ $\subset A'$, it follows that x must be a limit point of $A'$.

So my questions are:

**1. What is wrong with my contradiction in the 2 examples? Please explain them to me.
2. Is my proof for the lemma correct? I am going to use it for the proof that closure set is closed.**

My background: I am studying elementary Real Analysis by starting with Abbot. I thank you very much for your help.

**Extra question**: We have this theorem: x is a limit point of set $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(a_n) \subset A$ such that $\lim (a_n)=x$ $\forall a_n \neq x$. So, for some finite $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n = x$, x is still a limit point of set A . Is this correct? I thought that x would be an isolated points since we need $a_n \neq x \forall n \in \mathbb N$

I thank you again for your answers.

Comment: The variable $n$ here is internal to the construction of $\mathbf{A}$. Using it outside of that construction should raise a red flag. In fact, to determine $\mathbf{V}_\epsilon(0) \cap \mathbf{A}$ find the smallest $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/m < \epsilon$ (Why can I do this? I'm using two major facts about numbers.); then the intersection is $\{1/k : k \geq m\}$. Tons of points in there.

Comment: Oh my, I do not know why somebody votes down this post. I am just an introductory real analysis learner who is self-studying the subject. Is ignorance a sin when I am trying to fix it ?

Comment: It might have been the title. Probably one has to come to terms with the fact that thousands of people use the site and that some of them are bound to be harsh. The points mean nothing and you're on the road to understanding better a piece of mathematics, so on the whole I think things are okay.

Comment: I am wondering whether you are thinking more of the boundary of $A$ rather than the closure of $A$. The closure of a set is the set plus its boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding the lemma**: Suppose $x$ is a limit point of $A$. Then *every* **neighborhood** of $x$ contains a point in $A$ that is different than $x$. Since $A \subseteq A'$, then we can clearly see that these **neighborhoods** certainly contain a point in $A'$. The reason for this is because these neighborhoods contained at least a point in $A$, and we know $A$ is a subset of $A'$, so every point in $A$ is also in $A'$.

Using your proof: suppose there exists $(a_n) \rightarrow x$, and $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A$. We know $a_n \neq x$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. Since $A$ is subset of $A'$, we must have that $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A'$. Therefore, since we have the existence of a sequence in $A'$ that converges to $x$ where  $a_n \neq x$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, we must have that $x$ is a limit point of $A'$.

**In your second example**, remember a set is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points. Your "contradiction" is wrong; $[a,b]$ contains its limit points (you mentioned that $(a,b)$ has limits $a$ and $b$), so therefore it is closed. You based your contradiction on the fact that "the neighborhood of any point in $\bar A = [a,b]$ will intersect $\bar A = [a,b]$ at that same point," but those same neighborhoods will also intersect *other*, distinct points in $[a,b]$. This means that *every* point in $[a,b]$ is a limit point, whereas you said *no points* were limit points. They *all* are.

**Extra question**: No, if the sequence has a term that is *equal* to $x$, then $x$ is not a limit point. The sequence of points must be in $A\backslash \{x\}$. The theorem is: "$x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence in $A$ whose limit is $x$ and none of the terms in the sequence are equal to $x$". Or "$x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence in $A\backslash \{x\}$ whose limit is $x$."

Comment: So, x is also a limit point of $A'$ , right?

Comment: Yes, because let's say we found a neighborhood around $x$, $N(x)$, that also contains a point in $A$. Let's say this point is $a$. Since $a$ is *also* in $A'$ (by the assumption that $A \subseteq A'$), then that neighborhood we found earlier, $N(x)$, contains a distinct point that is in $A'$, namely the point $a$. So therefore, by definition, $x$ is a limit point of $A'$.

Comment: We have this theorem: x is a limit point of set $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(a_n) \subset A$ such that $\lim (a_n)=x$ $\forall a_n \neq x$. So, for some finite $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n = x$, x is still a limit point of set A if we follow your explanation. Is this correct? I thought that x would be an isolated points since we need $a_n \neq x \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Comment: I updated my answer :)

Comment: Can you please see my new question? I also do not know how to deal with it. I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Extra question: So, x is an isolated point ?

Comment: Remember that $x$ would be an isolated point of $A$ if $x \in A$ and we can find a neighborhood of $x$ that contains *no* other points in $A$.

Comment: No, it is not. But the definition in my book (Abbot) states: x is an isolated point if it is not a limit point. Then obviously, x must be an isolated point.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is correct, I forgot about that characterization of an isolated point. A point $x$ is an isolated point of $A$ if and only if it is not a limit point of $A$.

Comment: OK! THIS SOLVED MY QUESTIONS. I THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I HOPE I COULD TALK MORE DIRECTLY WITH YOU MORE WHEN I HAVE SOMETHING THAT I DO NOT KNOW.

Comment: No problem @SONTO :) I'm really glad I could help, and I'm glad you understand everything!

Answer (score 1):

In the first case your neighbourhood of zero includes $\frac 1{n+1}, \frac 1{n+2} \dots$

In the second case I'm not sure what you mean. Any neighbourhood of a point in $[a,b]$ (we take $b\gt a$) intersects $[a,b]$ in (a set containing) an interval around the point. And any point within $[a,b]$ is a limit point.

Comment: x is a limit point of set A if every $\epsilon$ -neighborhood intersects set A at points different from x. How can any point within $\left[a,b\right]$ be a limit point if its $\epsilon$-neighborhood intersects the closed interval at its limit point?

Comment: @SONTO Oh I see. Each neighborhood intersects the closure in at least some point other than the original point. But the intersection can include the original point. It just has to ALSO include some OTHER point. That's how we can preclude calling an isolated point a limit point. Because an isolated point has a neighborhood that ONLY contains the point. A point is a limit point if every neighborhood of the point contains the point and ALSO contains points that AREN'T the original point. Of course every neighborhood of a point contains that point!

Comment: @SONTO Take the interval $[0,1]$ and the neighbourhood of zero $[0,\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon \gt 0$. This neighbourhood contains the point $\frac {\epsilon}2$

Comment: @user4894 I thank you very much for your answer. What about my proof for the lemma, is it correct? Can you please give me answer instead of comments so that I can put a check on your answers?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, recall that the notion of limit point has a meaning only for *subsets*  of the real numbers (or, more generally but not too generally, of a metric space).

A point $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, the interval $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ contains a point of $A$ *different from* $x$.

Equivalently, $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$, with $a_n\ne x$ for all $n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$.

This is linked to your extra question. If a finite number of terms of a sequence $(a_n)$ equal $x$, then there exists $k$ such that $a_n\ne x$ for all $n>k$. Then define $b_n=a_{n+k}$: the sequence $(b_n)$ has all terms different from $x$ and, if $(a_n)$ converges to $x$, also $(b_n)$ converges to $x$.

Let's look at your “contradictions”. Note that nowhere in the definition it is required that a limit point of $A$ doesn't belong to $A$.

For instance, *every point of $[0,1]$ is a limit point of $[0,1]$.* Indeed, if $0< x\le1$, let $n_0$ be the first natural number such that $1/n_0<x$. Then $x-1/n_0>0$ and the sequence $$a_n=x-\frac{1}{n+n_0}$$ is in $[0,1]$ and converges to $x$, without ever assuming the value $x$. For $0$, just consider $a_n=1/n$.

Similarly, $0$ is a limit point of $\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N},n>0\}$. In this case, however, no other point is a limit point. So this set contains each of its limit points and is closed.

The important thing to note is that *a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$ without ever assuming the value $x$ must exist*, not that every sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$ shouldn't assume the value $x$. A sequence in $A$ showing that $x$ is a limit point is good for proving that $x$ is a limit point of the closure of $A$ as well!

Your proof of the lemma is good. In particular, it confirms that a limit point of $A$ is also a limit point of the closure of $A$.